# implicit conversion loses integer precision 'long' to 'int'

Tags: objective-c

I have a problem getting this problem fixed on xcode don't no why it happens it says 
implicit conversion loses integer precision 'long' to 'int'

```
[self newScheduleNotification:[ud objectForKey:dateKey] addNotifKey:[sw tag] ];
```

Comment: You know, without any info on the data types involved there's no way anyone can help you.

Comment: We need more code. Please add the method signature for `newScheduleNotification`, and let us know what type `tag` returns.

Answer (score 0):

This warning appears, if you assign a integer value (L-value) of type `long` to a variable (R-Value) of type `int`. This includes passing arguments of type `long` to parameters of type `int`. Probably you do that at `[sw tag]`.

"Integer precision lost" means that the `long` expression delivering the value might have a value that cannot be represented by the `int` destination.

Answer (score 0):

Change your type for `notifKey` to `NSInteger` in `newScheduleNotification:addNotifKey:`. You're passing it an `NSInteger`, which is a `long` on 64-bit, and an `int` on 32-bit, but your method is asking for an `int`. Using `NSInteger` in both places will handle the type for you. You must be on a 64-bit simulator or device. If you ran on a 32-bit sim or device you'll see the warning goes away because then you're passing an `int` to a method looking for an `int`.